# MySQL Join the Best Option Here?

Tags: mysql, sql

#### campaigns:

```
id     name            cap
1      Campaign1       2
2      Campaign2       1
3      Campaign3       1
```

#### served:

```
id     id_campaign     ip
1      1               127.0.0.1
2      1               127.0.0.1
3      2               127.0.0.1
```

The result of the query should display:

```
campaigns_id    campaigns_name          cap    count
1               Campaign1               2      2
2               Campaign2               1      1
3               Campaign3               1      0
```

I am using this query:

```
   SELECT served.id_campaign, 
          campaigns.name, 
          campaigns.cap, 
          COUNT( served.id ) AS count
     FROM campaigns
LEFT JOIN served ON campaigns.id = served.id_campaign
    WHERE served.ip =  '127.0.0.1' 
 GROUP BY served.id_campaign
```

My query is displaying these results (bad, not showing campaigns_id.3):

```
campaigns_id    campaigns_name          cap    count
1               Campaign1               2      2
2               Campaign2               1      1
```

I am thinking I am approaching wrong if I want to include values that aren't being selected by the "WHERE" statement as there are no records in "served" that match the WHERE statement for campaigns.id='3'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NEW EDIT:

```
   SELECT campaigns.id as id_campaign, 
          campaigns.name, 
          campaigns.cap, 
          COUNT( served.id ) AS count
     FROM campaigns
LEFT JOIN served ON campaigns.id = served.id_campaign
      AND served.ip =  '127.0.0.1' 
 GROUP BY campaigns.id
```

OLD POST:

I came up with this query, which produces the result you want:

```
(SELECT served.id_campaign, 
          campaigns.name, 
          campaigns.cap, 
          COUNT( served.id ) AS count
     FROM campaigns
LEFT JOIN served ON campaigns.id = served.id_campaign
    WHERE served.ip =  '127.0.0.1' 
 GROUP BY served.id_campaign)

UNION

(SELECT id, name, cap, 0 as count 
FROM campaigns 
WHERE id <> ALL 
     (
      SELECT campaigns.id 
      FROM campaigns, served 
      WHERE campaigns.id = served.id_campaign AND served.ip = "127.0.0.1"
     )
)
```

Comment: This worked but the query took 26 seconds to load. "served" has over 300,000 rows. Perhaps there is a way to perform the query without having to query through "served" twice.

Comment: I edited the post with new query. It's just corrected query from Andriy M. I think it should work and it queries the table "served" just once. Enjoy!

Comment: I think that it's a good idea to replace `served.id_campaign` with `campaigns.id` in the SELECT list. Your new query seems now to want just one correction: the GROUP BY clause should probably be `GROUP BY campaigns.id`. (UPDATE: I took the liberty to edit your post accordingly. If you do not agree, please feel free to roll back the change.)

Answer (score 0):

Change your where clause to

```
WHERE served.ip =  '127.0.0.1' OR served.ip IS NULL
```

Comment: Can't do this because I need to select records from "served" that match a specific IP. Doing this is essentially doing a WHERE 1=1 statement.

Comment: No it is not. It is basically saying show only records if the serverip is '127.0.0.1' or the server IP is not set. It will exclude all other ips.

Comment: I see what you are saying. I misread the answer. This will not work because there is always a value for served.ip and the missing row from "campaigns" are missing because there is no associated row in "served."

Answer (score -2):

LEFT JOIN says that bring all the records from left table and the matching records from the right hand side table. So the served.ip would be NULL from id=3.
So change the where condition to make it

```
WHERE serverd.ip = '127.0.0.1' or serverd.ip IS NULL
```

Comment: As you can see from the output I want (output below "The result of the query should display") I want to include result for id 3. LEFT JOIN and JOIN are returning the same outputs here.

Comment: ohh, I m sorry, I just skipped it. Try this served.ip = '127.0.0.1' or served.ip is NULL . The reason it would work is the served.ip in the resultset would either be empty or null. Hope it helps.